# Rally app setting 'Child Projects' does not work in Rally's own github source code

Tags: sdk, rally

I have compiled and installed the Custom Board app from Rally's GitHub --> https://github.com/RallySoftware/app-catalog/tree/master/src/apps/board

The biggest problem is this app ignores the 'Child Projects' setting in the app's 'Settings' menu.  It only shows objects from the selected project.  This behavior true of other Rally apps provided in the GitHub.  I suspect that something is amiss in all of the code uploaded to GitHub.  The apps however follow the global project settings for 'Child Projects' but just not the app's own scope settings.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to repro this and it seemed to work fine for me- both scoped to the global project + down and set to a specific project + down.  Are you sure the project you're scoped to has children?

Comment: Yes, the project has children.  In fact if I use Rally's app instead of my compiled version, it works just fine showing the children.

Comment: I'm showing user stories.  The layout is similar to the following,

- I have a parent project A with child projects B1 and B2.
- There exists a PF123 in parent project A, with child user stories spread across all 3 projects A, B1 and B2.
- I have a query in the app to show user stories that are children of the PF123 with the query (Feature.FormattedID = PF123)